# How to encode and decode SecretKey in JAVA?

Tags: java, cryptography

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
ks.load(null, null);
SecretKey skInput = new SecretKeySpec("input".getBytes(), "DESede");
SecretKeyEntry skeInput = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(skInput);
ks.setEntry("input_key", skeInput, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("banana".toCharArray()));
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("my.keystore");
pambks.store(fos, "password".toCharArray());
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

The code shown above is trying to encode the `input` into a SecretKey and store into keystore. The code shown below is how I retrieve the key from keystore. But I do not know how to decode it back to original value?

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("my.keystore");
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
ks.load(fin, "password".toCharArray());
SecretKeyEntry ske = (SecretKeyEntry) readks.getEntry("input_key", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("banana".toCharArray()));
SecretKey sk = ske.getSecretKey();
```

I wasn't sure whether this is the correct way of doing encryption and decryption to SecretKey, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Reading back this Q/A I think I've misread the question.

You can get the byte representation of the key back by calling the getEncoded method on you key. After that it is possible to use one of the String constructors to revert it back to text. As said, you should not use a string as key. Note that DES keys are contain parity in the last bit, so this may change the result. To use strings for keys it is more advisable to use hexadecimals. Note that keys should have enough entropy, and a string is not likely to provide that.

---

There are several things not entirely correct in the code above:

1. You should not (ever) use `"input".getBytes()`. First of all, `getBytes()` uses a platform specific default character encoding. If you want to use a DES key as a String, decode it with a decoder of hexadecimals (e.g. in Apache Commons codec or Bouncy Castle).
2. You should use 24 bytes for DESede keys. `"input".getBytes()` does not return enough bytes.
3. For DES keys it pays to put the key specification through a `KeyFactory` if only to make sure that the parity bits are set. They you will be sure that the key is valid.

To get a good amount of key data, use PBKDF2 for passwords or use randomly generated keys.

If an encrypted key store is good enough storage for an encrypted key depends on the use case and the other security measures.